# Python Django Model.save() saved wrong value in column

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm new in Django, and maybe question is dumb, but anyway...
I've problems with MyModel.save() saving in database, i'm trying to save some specific column which is used as filter in another part of my code... but this calue is not saving properly in Database as i expected from saving query...

models.py:

```
class TemplateAdvert(models.Model):
""" Черновик """
profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, verbose_name='Профиль пользователя', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,
                            null=True)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Категория 1', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                             blank=True)
category2 = models.ForeignKey(Category2, verbose_name='Категория 2', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                              blank=True)
category3 = models.ForeignKey(Category3, verbose_name='Категория 3', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                              blank=True)
category4 = models.ForeignKey(Category4, verbose_name='Категория 4', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                              blank=True)
subject = models.CharField('Тема', max_length=120, null=True,
                           blank=True)
description = models.TextField('Объявление', max_length=10000, null=True,
                               blank=True)
canton = models.CharField('Кантон', choices=Advert.CANTON_CHOICES, default='Zürich', max_length=100)
city = models.ForeignKey(City, verbose_name='Город', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
latlng_lat = models.DecimalField('Координаты latitude', max_digits=60, decimal_places=30, blank=True, null=True)
latlng_lng = models.DecimalField('Координаты longitude', max_digits=60, decimal_places=30, blank=True, null=True)
filters_vals = models.TextField('Значения фильтров', blank=True, null=True)
filters_vals_completed = models.BooleanField('Без фильтров', default=False)
images = models.ForeignKey(
    Gallery,
    verbose_name='Фото',
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL
)
is_bold = models.BooleanField('Выделено жирным', default=False)
bold_days = models.PositiveIntegerField('Осталось дней выделения жирным', default=0)
price = models.DecimalField('Цена', max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True,
                            blank=True)
exp_days = models.PositiveIntegerField('Осталось дней', default=0)
progress = models.PositiveIntegerField('Прогресс', default=0)
created = models.DateTimeField('Дата создания', auto_now_add=True)
country = models.CharField('ISO код страны', max_length=5, default='CH')
slug = models.SlugField('url', max_length=200)

def cat_path(self):
    ret = self.category.name
    if self.category2:
        ret += ' > ' + self.category2.name
    if self.category3:
        ret += ' > ' + self.category3.name
    return ret

def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.profile.user.username, self.subject)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    p = 0
    if self.category:
        p += 20
    if self.subject:
        p += 20
    if self.filters_vals_completed:
        p += 20
    if self.images:
        if self.images.complete:
            p += 20
    self.progress = p
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Черновик'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Черновики'
```

views.py, here I'm trying to save specific column in database:

```
    def profile_create_ad_template_save(request, username, step):
    if request.user.username == username:
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        currentCountry = settings.COUNTRY

        if step == 1:
            cats_ids = []
            for k, v in request.POST.items():
                if k[0:3] == 'cat':
                    cats_ids.append(v)
            qs = {
                'category': None,
                'category2': None,
                'category3': None,
                'category4': None
            }
            if len(cats_ids) >= 1:
                if len(Category.objects.filter(id=cats_ids[0], is_active=True)) == 1:
                    qs['category'] = Category.objects.get(id=cats_ids[0], is_active=True)
            if len(cats_ids) >= 2:
                if len(Category2.objects.filter(id=cats_ids[1], is_active=True)) == 1:
                    qs['category2'] = Category2.objects.get(id=cats_ids[1], is_active=True)
            if len(cats_ids) >= 3:
                if len(Category3.objects.filter(id=cats_ids[2], is_active=True)) == 1:
                    qs['category3'] = Category3.objects.get(id=cats_ids[2], is_active=True)
            if len(cats_ids) >= 4:
                if len(Category4.objects.filter(id=cats_ids[3], is_active=True)) == 1:
                    qs['category4'] = Category4.objects.get(id=cats_ids[3], is_active=True)
            qs['profile'] = profile
            t_id = request.POST.get('template_id')
            if len(t_id):
                template = TemplateAdvert.objects.filter(id=int(t_id))
                template.update(**qs)
                template = template[0]
            else:
                more_than_20 = TemplateAdvert.objects.filter(profile=profile).order_by('-created')[19:]
                for item in more_than_20:
                    item.delete()
                template = TemplateAdvert.objects.create(**qs)
            city_filter = False
            use_map = False
            for k, v in qs.items():
                if 'category' in k:
                    if v:
                        city_filter = v.city_filter
                        use_map = v.use_map
            response = {
                'success': True,
                'template_id': template.id,
                'city_filter': city_filter,
                'use_map': use_map,
                'path_to_marker': f'{settings.STATIC_URL}img/marker.png',
                'hex_color': get_hex_from_profile(profile)
            }
#            response['cantons'] = [{'id': canton.id, 'name': canton.canton_name} for canton in Canton.objects.all().order_by('canton_name')]
            if city_filter:
#                response['cities'] = [{'id': city.id, 'name': city.name} for city in City.objects.filter(canton=_canton)]
                response['cities'] = [{'id': city.id, 'name': city.name} for city in City.objects.all().filter(country=currentCountry).order_by('name')]
#            response['cantons'] = sorted([canton[0] for canton in Advert.CANTON_CHOICES])
            response['cantons'] = sorted([canton.canton_name for canton in Canton.objects.all().filter(country=currentCountry).order_by('canton_name')])
            return JsonResponse(response)
        if step == 2:
            response = {'success': False}
            template_id = request.POST.get('template_id')
            if template_id:
                if len(TemplateAdvert.objects.filter(id=template_id)) == 1:
                    template = TemplateAdvert.objects.get(id=template_id)
                    template.subject = request.POST.get('subject')
                    template.description = request.POST.get('description')
                    if 'city' in request.POST.keys():
                        template.city = City.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('city'))
                    if 'latlng-lat' in request.POST.keys():
                        template.latlng_lat = request.POST.get('latlng-lat')
                        template.latlng_lng = request.POST.get('latlng-lng')
                    if 'canton' in request.POST.keys():
                        template.canton = request.POST.get('canton')
                    template.country = currentCountry
                    template.save()
                    all_main_params_select = []
                    all_main_params_other = []
                    all_additional_params = []
                    if template.category2:
                        all_main_params_select.extend(p2 for p2 in template.category2.params.filter(type='select'))
                        all_main_params_other.extend(
                            p2 for p2 in template.category2.params.exclude(type='bool').exclude(type='select'))
                        all_additional_params.extend(p2 for p2 in template.category2.params.filter(type='bool'))
                    if template.category3:
                        all_main_params_select.extend([p3 for p3 in template.category3.params.filter(type='select')])
                        all_main_params_other.extend(
                            [p3 for p3 in template.category3.params.exclude(type='bool').exclude(type='select')])
                        all_additional_params.extend([p3 for p3 in template.category3.params.filter(type='bool')])
                    if template.category4:
                        all_main_params_select.extend([p4 for p4 in template.category4.params.filter(type='select')])
                        all_main_params_other.extend(
                            [p4 for p4 in template.category4.params.exclude(type='bool').exclude(type='select')])
                        all_additional_params.extend([p4 for p4 in template.category4.params.filter(type='bool')])
                    if len(all_main_params_select):
                        response['main_params_select'] = [
                            {
                                'id': param.id,
                                'name': param.name,
                                'required': param.required,
                                'options': [
                                    {
                                        'id': param_item.id,
                                        'text': param_item.name
                                    }
                                    for param_item in ParamItem.objects.filter(param=param)
                                ]
                            }
                            for param in all_main_params_select
                        ]
                    if len(all_main_params_other):
                        response['main_params_other'] = [
                            {
                                'name': param.name,
                                'type': ('text' if param.type == 'str' else 'number'),
                                'id': param.id,
                                'required': param.required,
                            }
                            for param in all_main_params_other
                        ]
                    if len(all_additional_params):
                        response['additional_params'] = [
                            {
                                'id': param.id,
                                'name': param.name,
                                'checks': [
                                    {
                                        'id': param_item.id,
                                        'name': param_item.name
                                    }
                                    for param_item in ParamItem.objects.filter(param=param)
                                ]
                            }
                            for param in all_additional_params
                        ]
                    response['success'] = True
            return JsonResponse(response)
        if step == 3:
            response = {'success': False}
            template_id = request.POST.get('template_id')
            if template_id:
                if len(TemplateAdvert.objects.filter(id=template_id)) == 1:
                    template = TemplateAdvert.objects.get(id=template_id)
                    data = ''
                    bool_params = {}
                    exclude_items = ['csrfmiddlewaretoken', 'template_id']
                    required_params = []
                    if template.category2:
                        for param in template.category2.params.filter(required=True):
                            required_params.append(param.id)
                    if template.category3:
                        for param in template.category3.params.filter(required=True):
                            required_params.append(param.id)
                    if template.category4:
                        for param in template.category4.params.filter(required=True):
                            required_params.append(param.id)
                    required = []
                    for param in required_params:
                        if str(param) not in request.POST.keys():
                            required.append({'id': param})
                        elif not request.POST[str(param)]:
                            required.append({'id': param})
                    if not len(required):
                        for k, v in request.POST.items():
                            if v:
                                if len(v) <= 12:
                                    if v == 'on':
                                        pid = k.split('_')[0]  # Param ID
                                        piid = k.split('_')[1]  # ParamItem ID
                                        if pid not in bool_params:
                                            bool_params[pid] = [piid]
                                        else:
                                            bool_params[pid].append(piid)
                                    elif k not in exclude_items:
                                        param = Param.objects.get(id=int(k))
                                        value = v
                                        if param.type == 'select':
                                            value = ParamItem.objects.get(id=int(value)).slug
                                        data += '\r\n' + param.type + ':' + param.slug + ':' + value
                        data = data[2:]
                        for pid, piid_mass in bool_params.items():
                            data += '\r\nbool:' + Param.objects.get(id=int(pid)).slug + ':'
                            for piid in piid_mass:
                                data += ParamItem.objects.get(id=int(piid)).slug + ', '
                            data = data[:-2]
                        template.filters_vals = data
                        template.filters_vals_completed = True
                        template.country = currentCountry
                        template.save()
                        response['success'] = True
                    else:
                        response['required'] = required
            return JsonResponse(response)
        if step == 4:
            response = {'success': False}
            template_id = request.POST.get('template_id')
            if template_id:
                if len(TemplateAdvert.objects.filter(id=template_id)) == 1:
                    template = TemplateAdvert.objects.get(id=template_id)
                    indexes = request.POST.get('indexes')
                    gal_name = '{}-template{}'.format(profile.user.username, template.id)
                    if Gallery.objects.filter(name=gal_name):
                        gal = Gallery.objects.get(name=gal_name)
                    else:
                        gal = Gallery.objects.create(name=gal_name, slug=gal_name, country=currentCountry)
                    for i in range(len(indexes)):
                        img_name = 'gallery{}-photo{}'.format(gal.id, indexes[i])
                        template.images.images.filter(slug=img_name).update(order=i+1)
                    template.images.images.all().update(is_main=False)
                    template.images.images.filter(order=1).update(is_main=True)
                    template.images.complete = True
                    template.images.save()
                    template.images.country = currentCountry
                    template.save()
                    response['success'] = True
            return JsonResponse(response)
        if step == 5:
            response = {'success': False}
            template_id = request.POST.get('template_id')
            if template_id:
                if len(TemplateAdvert.objects.filter(id=template_id)) == 1:
                    template = TemplateAdvert.objects.get(id=template_id)
                    is_bold = True if request.POST.get('is_bold') == 'on' else False
                    bold_days = 0
                    if is_bold:
                        bold_days = request.POST.get('bold_days')
                    if 'price' in request.POST.keys():
                        template.price = request.POST.get('price')
                    price_per_meter_filter = False
                    last_cat = template.category
                    if template.category2:
                        price_per_meter_filter = template.category2.price_per_meter_filter
                        last_cat = template.category2
                    if template.category3:
                        price_per_meter_filter = template.category2.price_per_meter_filter
                        last_cat = template.category3
                    if template.category4:
                        price_per_meter_filter = template.category4.price_per_meter_filter
                        last_cat = template.category4
                    if price_per_meter_filter and template.price:
                        for line in template.filters_vals.split('\r\n'):
                            if 'meters2' in line:
                                meters_square = float(line.split('meters2:')[1])
                                template.filters_vals += '\r\nint:price-per-meters2:' + str(round(float(template.price)/meters_square, 2))
                    exp_days = request.POST.get('exp_days')
                    template.is_bold = is_bold
                    template.bold_days = bold_days
                    template.exp_days = exp_days
                    template.country = currentCountry
                    template.save()
                    response = {
                        'success': True,
                        'enough_points': (True if int(template.exp_days) * last_cat.points_days_price + int(template.bold_days) * last_cat.points_bold_days_price <= profile.points else False),
                        'days': exp_days,
                        'bold_days': bold_days
                    }
            return JsonResponse(response)
    return error403(request, 'No Permissions')
```

but when I'm doing `SELECT country from table` I got different value from what I'm saving in views.py... also this value is different from SQL query which I've got from logging queryies in Django console...

logged query:

```
(0.005) UPDATE "my_app_templateadvert" SET "profile_id" = 60, "category_id" = 14, "category2_id" = 213, "category3_id" = 2120, "category4_id" = NULL, "subject" = 'test comment LV', "description" = 'test comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LV', "canton" = 'testCountryCanton', "city_id" = 163, "latlng_lat" = NULL, "latlng_lng" = NULL, "filters_vals" = NULL, "filters_vals_completed" = false, "images_id" = NULL, "is_bold" = false, "bold_days" = 0, "price" = NULL, "exp_days" = 0, "progress" = 40, "created" = '2023-04-15T16:54:06.747890+00:00'::timestamptz, "country" = 'LV', "slug" = '' WHERE "my_app_templateadvert"."id" = 145; args=(60, 14, 213, 2120, 'test comment LV', 'test comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LVtest comment LV', 'testCountryCanton', 163, False, False, 0, 0, 40, datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 15, 16, 54, 6, 747890, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'LV', '', 145); alias=default
```

so can anyone help me with this mistake?

P.S Django 4.1.1
P.P.S database is same and it's set in settings.py

Comment: It's harder for us to help when the log output does not agree with the code.  For example the code has `MyModel`, but in the log, the actual model name is (apparently) `templateadvert`.

Comment: In the view code, if you print the object before calling `.save()`, that should tell you more about which exact instance is being updated, and what exact fields are being set.

Comment: 1) Add the complete model code to the question 2) Best bet is you are saving to different database then the one you think you are.

Comment: @JohnGordon see edited question with full model/view code

Comment: How are we supposed to figure this out?:  1) There are 5 steps in the view and 4 template.save() operations and no indication of which one is causing the  issue. 2) Also there is no explanation of what the issue is? *but when I'm doing SELECT country from table I got different value from what I'm saving in views.py... also this value is different from SQL query which I've got from logging queryies in Django console...*  has no detail on what the input data is and what the expected data is and what is actually returned? At this point this is unanswerable.